# This is my image insert into database.but it won't show image path or image in folder?

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

This is my image insert into database.but it won't show image path or image in folder?
This code shows err=imgpro this error in URL.
 Any idea ?
If possible edit my code and post it in comment.
Also want add multiple checkbox and its value into the database.

```
<?php
include "config.php";
extract($_POST);
$file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["img"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "img/gif")
|| ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "img/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "img/png")
|| ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "img/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["img"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
{
if ($_FILES["img"]["error"] > 0)
{
header("Location: Add_Decoration_Item_form.php?err=imgpro1");
//echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["img"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
$tempupname = time().$_FILES["img"]["name"];
$imgpathtostore="imgs/".$tempupname;
$imgpathtostoreDB="imgs/".$tempupname;
// Enter your path to upload file here

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $imgpathtostore);

$sql= "INSERT INTO user_regi.u_reg (u_id, u_name, u_gender, u_mail, u_pwd, u_dob,u_hobbies,u_image,u_about) VALUES (NULL, '$uname', '$gender', '$email', '$pwd', '$DOB',$team, $img,'$about')";


mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
echo mysqli_errno();
/*header("Location: Form.php?msg=err");*/
}
else
{
header("Location: Form.php?msg=ok");

}
}
}

else
{
header("Location: Form.php?err=imgpro");
}

?>
```

Any Helpful answers?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$sql` you store a variable called `$img`, but it is never set, you should store `$imgpathtostoreDB` instead. Which contains the path to your image.

Comment: i tried also $imgpathtostoreDB but it didn't work. Any other idea?